# Large graph as input to find all paths

Tags: python, graph, shortest-path, bigdata

I'm using the following python code in order to find all paths between each two nodes. It's not any problem for small graphs.

```
def bfs(graph, start, end):
    # maintain a queue of paths
    queue = []
    # push the first path into the queue
    queue.append([start])
    while queue:
        # get the first path from the queue
        path = queue.pop(0)
        # get the last node from the path
        node = path[-1]
        # path found
        if node == end:
            return path
        # enumerate all adjacent nodes, construct a new path and push it into the queue
        for adjacent in graph.get(node, []):
            new_path = list(path)
            new_path.append(adjacent)
            queue.append(new_path)

for node3 in graph:
        for node4 in graph:
            few = bfs(graph, node3, node4)
            if not few == None:
                print ("{0} -> {1}".format(node3,node4))
                print (few)
                print ("\n")
```

But, I want to find all paths between each two nodes, for a large graph with about 4K nodes and 20K edges. The program intrupts and doesn't return any output.

May you please help me how to set the input graph and also, how to set the output to add in a separated file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is it may **couldn't be done**, **except** the case that your graph is a special graph, number of paths between two nodes in such graph may be enormous.consider following case:
For a complete graph of 200 vertices and 20K edges there is **198!/2** different paths between any two vertices.
If your graph contains a cycle then there is **infinite** paths in it.

Your graph could be have such number of paths between two vertices that even a super computer couldn't compute the number in a decade.

Comment: It is just a part of a social network and I think It isn't a huge graph with millions number of nodes and edges. It has about 20K edges.

Comment: I think we may avoid cycles as Modified DFS.

Comment: Also, I think it is BFS and BFS avoids from cycles

Comment: @SiavashR still the number could be very large. You can test it to exit when number exceeds a fixed value, to see if the number is suitable or not.